# npm warn deprecated and npm errors

Tags: npm, deprecated, truffle

I tried to install truffle and all these deprecated messages and errors occured , i checked the npm modules version  with 'npm-check -u' and it says it is all good.
I searched everywhere for a solution but nothing worked .
Iam looking for your help ,thanks in advance .

[view code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBbzG.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it suggests you to install visual studio, which will install C and C++ tools. For the most part, those warnings do not mean much, as this is a local development framework, and I get them on the windows truffle install as well, but i am not sure why, but node-gyp wants a C compiler. here is the link to visual studio: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/free-developer-offers/